# Recycler view that should change according to filter doesn't update correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity that shows a edit text where the user can input a filter and a recycler view that shows a list of cities that contain the information on that filter... However, I have an issue where the recycler view  size updates to match the sql query result but does not change the information itself (i.e. if the sql query returns 4 cities the recycle view shows the first 4 cities in alphabetical order). What could be happening?

My adapter and my activity, respectively:

```
public class FilterCidadeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterCidadeAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<Cidade> data;
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerView list;
    public ArrayList<Cidade> cidades = new ArrayList<>();

    public FilterCidadeAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Cidade> data){
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FilterCidadeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        list = (RecyclerView) parent;

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_cidade_filtered, parent,false);

        FilterCidadeAdapter.ViewHolder mh = new FilterCidadeAdapter.ViewHolder(v);

        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FilterCidadeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Cidade item = data.get(position);
        final DataBaseHelper db = Sessao.getInstance().getDb(context);
        holder.nome.setText(item.getCidade());

        holder.btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ListaProspeccoesActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("selection", item.getCidade());
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cidades.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView nome;
        ImageButton btnSelect;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.nome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Cidade);
            this.btnSelect = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_selecionar);
        }
    }
}



public class FilterProspeccaoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText et_cidade_filtro;
    private RecyclerView lista;
    private LinearLayout linear;
    private int cont = 0;
    private  FilterCidadeAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fitrar_cidade);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#009342"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


        et_cidade_filtro = findViewById(R.id.et_filtrar_cidade);


        Cidade cidade = new Cidade(-1, "CIDADES", "");
        ArrayList<Cidade> cidades = cidade.getAll(FilterProspeccaoActivity.this, null);
//        cidades.add(0, cidade);
        lista = findViewById(R.id.list_cidade);

        adapter = new FilterCidadeAdapter(FilterProspeccaoActivity.this,R.layout.item_cidade_filtered,cidades);
        try {
            LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

            lista.setLayoutManager(lm);
            lista.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(lista.getContext(), lm.getOrientation()));
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    cont = 1;
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
                }
            }, 500);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            lista.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            apagarLista();
        }

        et_cidade_filtro.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                reload();
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void apagarLista() {
        linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        reload();
    }

    public void reload() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DataBaseHelper db = Sessao.getInstance().getDb(FilterProspeccaoActivity.this);
                Cidade cidade = new Cidade();
                ArrayList<Cidade> cidades = cidade.findCidadesByNome(FilterProspeccaoActivity.this, et_cidade_filtro.getText().toString());

                adapter.cidades.clear();
                adapter.cidades.addAll(cidades);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

            }

        });
        thread.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the query is actually returning what you expect?

Comment: Within the `reload()` you didn't use the database `db` variable to get the filtered data.. Also the piece of code: `ArrayList<Cidade> cidades = cidade.findCidadesByNome(FilterProspeccaoActivity.this, et_cidade_filtro.getText().toString())` looks like that it has the issue

Comment: The query is returning correctly, the variable `cidades` in the `reload()` method contains the correct information until at least the `adapter.cidades.addAll(cidades)`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the adapters current list, `adapter.cidades = cidades`